# Filter out find results where I may not read file / see directory contents

Tags: bash, find

Example:

```
find / *
```

Gives me all files and directories, but **I want only those files I may read and those directories I may see the contents of**. Otherwise I get problems as when I try to find file information for all files:

```
for i in ls $( find / * ); do file $i; done
```

Which results in:

```
find: /lost+found: Permission denied
find: /proc/tty/driver: Permission denied
find: /proc/1/task/1/fd: Permission denied
find: /proc/1/fd: Permission denied
find: /proc/2/task/2/fd: Permission denied
find: /proc/2/fd: Permission denied
find: /proc/3/task/3/fd: Permission denied
# and so on ...
```

If it's possible I would like it in a **generic way, so that I may use the same command line regardless of which user I am logged in as**, but still get those files and directories I may see as a result from find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-readable` option to `find` (assuming a modern system using GNU [findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/)):

> Matches  files  which  are  readable. 
>   This  takes into account access
>   control lists and other permissions
>   artefacts  which  the
>   -perm test ignores.  This test makes use of the access(2) system call, and
>   so can be fooled by NFS servers which
>   do  UID  mapping (or  root-squashing),
>   since many systems implement access(2)
>   in the client’s kernel and so cannot
>   make use of  the  UID  mapping
>   information held on the server.

Using `-perm` and variants doesn't work because it only looks at the file's flags, and not whether those flags give *you* access.

If you *don't* have `-readable`, you can pipe the output of `find` through this trivial Perl script which only outputs the file names of the supplied files that are readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use POSIX qw[access];
use strict;

foreach (split(/\0/, <STDIN>)) {
    print $_ . "\0" if (POSIX::access($_, &POSIX::R_OK));
}
```

e.g.

```
% find / -print0 | access_test | xargs -0 -n 1 do_cmd
```

but note that this will still generate output errors on `stderr` as `find` attempts to recurse into directories that it doesn't have permission for.  The `print0` option to `find` (and `xargs -0`) is there to make sure that the system works on file names with embedded spaces in them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did look at -perm before posting and it didn't seem to be for me. And it seems I'm not using a modern system, I'm using Fedora at the moment and -readable doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: It's present on my Fedora 10 system.

Comment: I've got Fedora release 7 (Moonshine) where I am (at the university) and I don't got admin rights. When I get home I've got Ubuntu 8.04 which I bet got it too. :-)

Comment: Actually no, it wasn't available by default in Ubuntu 8.04. But at home at least I can install it.

Comment: `-readable` does not help against directories without listing permission.

Comment: The OP said he only cares about directories he can see the contents of.